# Difference between the address of the variable that points to an array and the value of that variable itself

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I have an array

```
int ar[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
printf("%d",(ar==&ar));
```

The print statement returns true. But what if I do `ar+1` and `&ar+1`. Where does that point to?

Also if I have

```
char *c[] = {"GeksQuiz", "MCQ", "TEST", "QUIZ"};
char **cp[] = {c+3, c+2, c+1, c};
char ***cpp = cp;
```

where does cpp+1 point to? Is it after `cp` i.e. `cp[4]` or does it point to `cp[1]`?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the pointers? i.e. with `%p`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address of an array corresponds to the location of the array object in memory, and has type "pointer to array". This location has the same value as the address of the first element of the array. The address of the first element of the array is what an array name will decay into when used in an expression. This explains why `ar == &ar`.

Now, as `ar` decays to the address of the first element, the `ar + 1` is the address of the second element of the array. However, the value of `&ar` has type pointer to an array, and so `&ar + 1` actually points after the `ar` array itself, which would be address of the object just past its last element (or `&ar[5]`).

Your `c`, `cp`, and `cpp` arrays can be pictorially represented like this:

```
                      "GeksQuiz"      "MCQ"    "TEST"       "QUIZ"
                      ^               ^        ^            ^
               c:     |               |        |            |
               +---+  |               |        |            |
     +-------->| *----+               |        |            |
     |         +---+                  |        |            |
     | +------>| *--------------------+        |            |
     | |       +---+                           |            |
     | | +---->| *-----------------------------+            |
     | | |     +---+                                        |
     | | | +-->| *------------------------------------------+
     | | | |   +---+
     | | | |
     | | | |   cp:
     | | | |   +---+
     | | | +-----* |<--+
     | | |     +---+   |
     | | +-------* |   |
     | |       +---+   |
     | +---------* |   |
     |         +---+   |
     +-----------* |   |
               +---+   |
                       |
                       |
               +---+   |
           cpp:| *-----+
               +---+
```

Since `cpp` is a pointer variable, `cpp+1` is 1 greater than the value of that variable. The `cpp` variable contains the decayed value of `cp` (the address of its first element). So `cpp+1` is the same as `cp+1`, which would correspond to `&cp[1]`, or the address of the second element of `cp`.

Comment: Excellent explanation! One more thing : isn't `cpp` also an pointer to array?

Answer (score 2):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and its value will be the address of the first element of the array.

The expression `ar` has type "5-element array of `int`"; if it's not the operand of the `&` operator, it will be converted to type "pointer to `int`", and its value will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the expression `&ar`, `ar` is the operand of the unary `&` operator, so the conversion doesn't happen; in this case, the type of the expression is "pointer to 5-element array of `int`".

Both `ar` and `&ar` have the same *value* (the address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the whole array), but the types are different:

```
Expression     Type         Decays to
----------     ----         ---------
        ar     int [5]      int *
       &ar     int (*)[5]   n/a
```

`ar + 1` will point to the next `int` value (it's equivalent to writing `&ar[1]`).  `&ar + 1` will point to the next *5-element array of `int`* (that is, it will point to the `int` value immediately following the last element of the array).

`cpp + 1` will point to the next `char **` element (equivalent to writing `&cp[1]`).